# How can I handle a button that increments a count and saves it to the database?

Tags: javascript

I am just thinking through this before I build but I want to have a button on a post that will increase the vote count for it.  The local variable/state will change immediately and in the same function, make a call to save the value to the database.  This is fine however if someone hammer clicks on that button and rapidly increments the vote, I don't want to keep making a database call each time. I am trying to think of ways to remedy that.  Would the best way to handle that be using a debounce function that will only call the database save call after X amounts of seconds from the last click ?

Comment: You may put in your local state a variable like `clicked: false`. When clicked, check if it is false, send the DB request and change to true.
Hint: Reloading the page will allow to vote again. But only once per load.

Comment: I think I am confused .. The term "vote' generally means someone is represented in a consensus being performed.  Having someone represented more than once, skews data doesn't it?  Or am I missing something.  Is it a contest to see how many times someone can click a button?

Comment: ah @Zak, you are 100% right.  In that case, I can just add a boolean field `voted` and not allow them to do anything if they voted already.   Thanks!